# Central Vaccum Wiring use?

Tags: central-vacuum

Our Central vacuum cover lid broke, So I was planning on replacing it. I removed it and noticed 2 sets of wires twisted.

What exactly are these for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for causing the vacuum to turn on when you plug a hose into the outlet, or plug a hose into the outlet and turn the switch built into the hose on.

It's generally a low-voltge relay setup in my experience.

Normally they would be connected to terminals on the vacuum outlet - not quite clear what's going on if they are just twisted together (and appear to have been painted at some point.) What is your normal procedure to turn the vacuum on - that might shed some light on this odd arrangement.

Comment: we have to go to where the vacuum unit is and manually turn it on everytime. I was seriously wondering if there was a better way in doing this.

Comment: There definitely IS a better way. You might need to do some checking to see if the wires are actually connected to the system - if so, you can either wire in a switch at each outlet, or use the outlets/hoses with built-in switches (if there are metal plates on the part of your hose that sticks into the outlet, it may already be the right kind, just not hooked up for some odd reason.)